Why destructor needs to be accessible even when it is not called?
Having class X, the following object initialization:
new (ptr) X(X());

requires an accessible destructor even since C++17. Why is that, when the object is initialized by the default constructor directly in the storage pointed to by ptr, so no temporary should be involved?
Example code:
struct X {
  X() { }
  X(const X&) = delete;
  X(X&&) = delete;
  ~X() = delete;  // or, e.g, private
};

void test(void* ptr) {
  new (ptr) X(X());  // error: attempt to use a deleted function
}

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Khac1z8r3
UPDATE
This is a similar question: Why is public destructor necessary for mandatory RVO in C++?. But my case is different, since in my code, the problem of potential destructor calls due to exceptions does not apply (or, at least, I can't see it there).

That innermost X() creates a temporary object that has to be destroyed.

@PeteBecker Doesn't mandatory copy elision prevent that?

@PeteBecker My understanding is that if there was a temporary, then the object would have to be initialized by copy or move constructor. Which no longer happens since C++17.

MSVC compiles it as is. Also if we use new (ptr) X; all 3 compilers accept it. See demo, so the possibly temporary innermost X() has something to do with the issue.

@HolyBlackCat I would expect so too... but considering where compilers come from. It might be copy elission is an optimization applied after the first pass. MSVC, at least a while ago, wouldn't even apply (if that's the correct word) copy elission in debug builds.

@PepijnKramer The "copy elision" term is very misleading for "deferred materialization" cases. AFAIK, there is nothing to elide here.

@DanielLangr -- maybe; but the error message in your godbolt link has an arrow pointing at that temporary. That's what the compiler is complaining about. Whether it's correct is a different question (one that I'm not qualified to comment on, since I stopped paying attention to the development of the standard several years ago)

From cppreference.com : "The destructor of the type returned must be accessible at the point of the return statement and non-deleted, even though no T object is destroyed.".

@Jarod42 Yes, this rule is related to values returned from functions, which is different from my case. There, I can understand the reasons (please, see the linked post in my update).

So (a) if this is illegal, it shouldn't be.   Even if X() { } throws there wouldn't be an X to destroy at that point.  And (b), I'd look into the guaranteed elision changes of the standard.  As @Jarod42 notes, requirement for non-used destructors in some cases is in the standard; the non-canonical source he mentions is talking about function return guaranteed elision, the actual standard may have related words for your case.

I think mandatory move elision still needs all the members that would have been necessary had elision not occurred to be accessible.

@FrançoisAndrieux I agree, but this is not move/copy elision. That's why, since C++17, we can write, e.g., std::atomic<int> a = 1;, which was not possible in C++11/14.

Is the inner X() a materialized temporary? This conversion requires an accessible destructor.

@FrançoisAndrieux At the end of the section you linked: "Note that temporary materialization does not occur when initializing an object from a prvalue of the same type (by direct-initialization or copy-initialization): such object is initialized directly from the initializer."

@DanielLangr you write "Yes, this rule is related to values returned from functions, which is different from my case.", but isn't a constructor invocation a function which returns a value of the type of the constructor? Elision aside?

@Maurycyt No, ctors don't actually return an object of the type of the class. See Constructors are functions that do not return a value.

@user12002570 I disagree with this interpretation. It is in fact stated, that ctors "do not return a value" but it seems to me like what is actually being said is that one cannot use return X in a ctor definition. So I think one should read this as "Constructors do not syntactically return a value". However, it is common to use a constructor call as an expression. Whether we use a constructor call directly or a function which only returns a value created by a constructor call is completely irrelevant since it has the same semantics. For all intents and purposes, it is a function as I wrote

@Maurycyt Yes, I already know it is a function. I've explained this in more detail here

Sorry I was running out of space and so I wrote slightly ambiguously. I meant, that it "is a function as I wrote", meaning that it is a function which "returns a value", as I stated above. Now naturally, it cannot "return a value" in its definition, but it still "returns a value" when called. Hence my initial comment, that Daniel incorrectly rejected the rule as not pertaining to constructors, but only to functions returning a value, when the constructor does, in fact, return a value, even if one cannot explicitly return it in the constructor's definition.

@Maurycyt Note also that constructors cannot be called directly in c++. They don't have a name. They are implicitly called by the compiler.

@user12002570 In my opinion, that just further supports my point. If calling X() does not actually call the constructor, then something else happens which looks like a function call of an implicitly defined function with the same name as class X. At which point that function returns a value, which contradicts Daniel's remark.

@Maurycyt There is one substantial difference between a "returning a value" from ordinary functions and constructors, which is relevant here. Ordinary functions 1) construct a return value and 2) destroy local objects. 2) may generally throw, and in such cases, the previously-constructed return value needs to be destructed (so the destructor is potentially-called as discussed here: https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2426.html). In my case, this problem does not apply; there is no need to potentially-destruct the constructed object if anyting fails.

@DanielLangr constructors can throw. In that case they may need to destroy some objects, including a fully constructed object which was being constructed in terms of data.

@Maurycyt Some objects, but not the constructed object itself. If constructor throws, destructor is not called. (With the exception of delegating constructors.)

The compilers are not behaving correctly (assuming C++17 or later).
In your code the destructor of X is not explicitly invoked, it is not implicitly invoked according to [class.dtor]/14 sentence 1 or sentence 3 and it is also not potentially invoked according to [class.dtor]/14 sentence 6.
In particular there is no implicit invocation of the destructor to destroy a temporary object, because none exists. The new-expression direct-initializes the object it creates from the initializer of the new expression. The single parenthesized argument in the initializer is a prvalue of type X and according to [dcl.init.general]/16.6.1 this means the destination object is immediately initialized from the initializer of the prvalue argument. No temporary materialization conversion happens.
Therefore, it ought to not matter that the destructor is deleted.
For Clang this seems to have been reported already a while ago, see bug report, but there hasn't been any activity on the report.
